# SL5 best option for a Win8 & WP8 development shop forced to develop a Win7 app?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-store-apps, mvvm-light, silverlight-5.0

We are a Win8 & WP8 (new) development shop that must develop a one-of internal use only LOB app that runs on Win7 (preferably out of browser).  Since most of our client-side app knowledge is with XAML/MVVM, I'm thinking our best option for that app is to do it in SL5.

So, how much of our XAML/MVVM knowledge can we leverage for SL5 development?  Can we actually share some amount of code between SL5 & Win8 if we design with MVVM clearly in mind?  What are the pitfalls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight?  No need.

The answer is simple and straightforward.  Move as much logic and types into one or more portable class library projects.  These can be used on WP8, Windows Store apps, and desktop apps, so there will be minimal effort using them in these types of applications.

For windows 7, go with WPF for your UI.  You may find that the API is slightly awkward to deal with, as it  lacks the asynchronous patterns that you have to use for WP8/WS applications, however developing the UI via xaml is exactly the same.  I don't think you'll find much of a difference at all between the two.

Comment: hmmm...  Thats interesting, hadn't considered WPF instead of SL.  I was looking at SL because I have dealt with it before, so can leverage that knowledge/experience.  Without getting into too far, since it is a very straightforward LOB application, wouldn't SL be "lower complexity"? Ive never dealt with WPF before, but am under the impression its a much bigger hammer...

Comment: @jwdaigle: The only difference between SL and WPF is that SL is a subset of WPF.  That means that WPF would be more flexible and easier to use.

Comment: If you are developing for the Windows desktop and want XAML based, then WPF should be the first consideration.  Silverlight's strength was its cross platform support (Windows, Mac) not it's desktop development cred.  It's wasn't until later versions of Silverlight that it even became close to being a desktop replacement technology.